# program for degree discount heuristic

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to implement the generalized degree discount heuristic.the code is given below. unable to get with this

am getting this result.

> 33696
>
> 180811
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "GeneralizedDegreeDiscount_test.py", line 33, in
>
> ```
> sumt[w]=sumt[w]+t[w]
> ```
>
> KeyError: 1

```
 import networkx as nx

G=nx.read_edgelist('email- Enron.txt',create_using=nx.Graph(),nodetype=int)
print G.number_of_nodes()
print G.number_of_edges()
k=10
p=0.01
S=[]
d=dict()
gdd=dict()
t=dict()
sumt=dict()
for v in G:
    d[v]=G.degree(v)
    gdd[v]=d[v]
    t[v]=0
for i in range(k):
    u, gddv = max(gdd.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v): v)
    gdd.pop(u)
    S.append(u)
    nb=[]
    for v in G[u]:
        nb.append(v)
        t[v]=t[v]+1
        for w in G[v]:
            nb.append(w)
    #print nb
    for v in nb:
        sumt[w]=0
        for w in G[v]:
            #sumt[w] = 0
            if w not in S:
                sumt[w]=sumt[w]+t[w]
        gdd[v] = d[v] - 2 * t[v] - (d[v] - t[v]) * t[v] * p + (1 / 2) * t[v] * (t[v] - 1) * p - sumt[w] * p
        if gdd[v] < 0:
            gdd[v] = 0
print 'final', S
```

Should get list with k size as result.

Comment: You're going to have another problem.  In `gdd[v] = ...` you have `sumt[w]`, which means it's going to use the very last `w` in `G[v]`.  I doubt very much that is your intent.  Are yo certain you want to be calculating `sumt[w]`, and not `sumt[v]` (especially given how you are trying to initialize it before even looping over `w`)?

Comment: ya, that is the problem am facing. where it should be initialized actually? according to paper on generalized degree discount heuristic i have done it.